# SonarQube custom rule for C# NullReferenceException handling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 6.2 in my C# projects. I have a method that checks an object if it's null or a nullentity

```
if (IsNullOrNullEntity(norm))
    sorte.FkNorm = null;
else
    sorte.FkNorm = norm.Pk;
```

SonarQube reports me now that I have a possible NullRefenceExpetion for norm.Pk -> but thats not the case because I check this in IsNullOrNullEntity().

Is there a way to "tell" SonarQube this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell the C# analyzer what the `IsNullOrNullEntity` method does, even if it was declared in the same class. The current implementation of our data-flow analysis works only in the scope of one method and cannot recognize what would be the output of an invoked method, given some input. We will be enhancing this functionality soon, but at this time I cannot commit to an exact date.

There are few things that can be done:

- If you are using SonarLint in connected mode, you could mark the issues in SonarQube as false positives. SonarLint will be able to hide issues in Visual Studio that are marked with false positive in the very near future (perhaps in a month or two).
- Do not use utility methods for null checking - apparently this will introduce some duplication, but the null checks will be much more accurate and in my opinion this rule is one of the several high-value rules that should not be disabled.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I faced the same issue. For ReSharper, I can define ContractAnnotation for my null-checker-method, so I can say [ContractAnnotation("dbObject:null => true")] bool IsNull(object dbObject, ...). It would be very helpful if you can implement something like this to avoid false positive results.